# Using isnull() function and subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 separate columns, 'ATFTE' and 'SATFTE'. Using these two columns, I have to perform division and store the result in a separate column (say Pyramid). I am trying to use isnull function, because in many cases, the denominator is 0 and bringing it in a subquery. It shows error - 'Invalid Column name' - ATFTE and SATFTE. How can I rectify it?

```
select isnull(ATFTE/SATFTE,0) as Pyramid
from dw_UtilizationPredictionReport
where WFMGrade in (
select WFMGrade,
    case 
        when WFMGrade IN ('P/PA','PAT','A') then sum(TotalFTE)
        else 0
    END as ATFTE,
    case
        when WFMGrade IN ('SA','M','SM','AD','D','SD','AVP','VP','SVP','EVP') 
        and WFMGrade NOT IN ('Cont') then sum(TotalFTE)
        else 0
    END as SATFTE
from dw_UtilizationPredictionReport
group by (WFMGrade)
)
```

Comment: Could you please provide it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  CASE WHEN ISNULL(SATFTE,0) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ISNULL(ATFTE/SATFTE,0) 
    END AS Pyramid FROM
(select WFMGrade,
    case 
        when WFMGrade IN ('P/PA','PAT','A') then sum(TotalFTE)
        else 0
    END as ATFTE,
    case
        when WFMGrade IN ('SA','M','SM','AD','D','SD','AVP','VP','SVP','EVP') 
        and WFMGrade NOT IN ('Cont') then sum(TotalFTE)
        else 0
    END as SATFTE
from dw_UtilizationPredictionReport
group by (WFMGrade)) as tbl
```

In your query it seems that you have done below mistakes:

1. You can not use the IN statement with multiple columns in the WHERE
   Clause.
2. ATFTE/SATFTE are not the columns of the table
   "dw_UtilizationPredictionReport", so you can not use it in the
   select.

Comment: It's showing an error - "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Comment: Yes, they are not the columns in the table, so how do I use these columns to perform division and store in a separate column?

Comment: I have updated the query to add the alias with the subquery. Try this.

Comment: It shows an error - Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: You may got the 0 for  "SATFTE"

Comment: @ Deepali Samtani, Have you checked the updated query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.WFMGrade, sum(b.TotalFTE) / sum(c.(TotalFTE)
from dw_UtilizationPredictionReport a
left join dw_UtilizationPredictionReport b 
on b.WFMGrade = a.WFMGrade 
and b.WFMGrade IN ('P/PA','PAT','A')
left join dw_UtilizationPredictionReport c 
on c.WFMGrade = a.WFMGrade 
and c.WFMGrade IN ('SA','M','SM','AD','D','SD','AVP','VP','SVP','EVP') 
group by a.WFMGrade
```

Try if this is working for you, you dont have to include not in for condition "Cont" since you are having the in condition.

Comment: The query is running for infinite time. I am not really sure, if this is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the first bit

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(SATFTE,0) = 0 THEN 0 -- Or whatever you want
        ELSE ISNULL(ATFTE/SATFTE,0) 
    END AS Pyramid
```